# Getting the clicked item from a ajax completed list

Tags: jquery, api, select

I am using a lookup for UK postcodes which generates a simple form, does an api call and them fills in the list with returned items:

```
<script>
$('#postcode_lookup').getAddress(
{
api_key: 'XXXXX',  
output_fields:
    {
    line_1: '#line1',
    line_2: '#line2',
    line_3: '#line3',
    post_town: '#town',
    county: '#county',
    postcode: '#postcode'
    },
input_label:'Please enter your postcode',
input_class:'form-control',
button_label:'Search',
button_class:'btn btn-primary'
});
</script>
```

So I end up with

[image]

What I now want to do is select one of the items and take the address line off to another page.

Any best way of doing this please?

Comment: I have tried (the reply generates a dropdown with the id of getaddress_dropdown):

    $(document).on("change", "#getaddress_dropdown", function() {
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using plug-in https://getaddress.io. This allows for custom code to be called by registering a callback method. The function you''ll want is `onAddressSelected`.

Below is an example for illustration purposes (as I don't have a valid license) of how to redirect to another page with the selected address.

```
$('#postcode_lookup').getAddress(
{
    api_key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    output_fields:
    {
        line_1: '#line1',
        line_2: '#line2',
        line_3: '#line3',
        post_town: '#town',
        county: '#county',
        postcode: '#postcode'
    },
    <!-- Optionally register callbacks at specific stages -->
    onLookupSuccess: function (data) {/* Your custom code */ },
    onLookupError: function () {/* Your custom code */ },
    onAddressSelected: function (elem, index) {
        /* Your custom code */
        window.location.replace("/other-page?address=" + index.formatted_address);
    }
});
```

You can read more about the documentation https://getaddress.io/Documentation (see JQuery link on left-hand-side)

Also the plugin provide API, which means you're not limited to JQuery.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I used the API after getting the postcode from a simple form, set up a table of postcodes and a postcode of addresses, checked to see if the postcode is in the database. If it is not I recorded the information and also put each address into a table. Then it is just a case of passing the id of the postcode to the view and showing the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a DropDownList?

**"What I now want to do is select one of the items and take the address line off to another page.
Any best way of doing this please?"**

(I actually honestly don't know the answer, or know 100% what you mean, but hope this helps in some kind of way)

the first thing that comes in my mind is a POST when you click on SUBMIT.

that or you want to submit with a onclick?

if that's the case,

```
<element onclick="this.form.submit()">
```

if you want to have the whole dropdownlist to another page, i think the easiest way is to have that part saved as a own page, like for instance, "DropDownListCode.php"

then you do: `<?php require_once('DropDownListCode.php'); ?>"`

In that page you save things like

```
<element id="postcode_lookup">
    <script>
        $('#postcode_lookup').getAddress(
        {
            api_key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
            output_fields:
            {
                line_1: '#line1',
                line_2: '#line2',
                line_3: '#line3',
                post_town: '#town',
                county: '#county',
                postcode: '#postcode'
            },
            <!-- Optionally register callbacks at specific stages -->
            onLookupSuccess: function (data) {/* Your custom code */ },
            onLookupError: function () {/* Your custom code */ },
            onAddressSelected: function (elem, index) {
                /* Your custom code */
                window.location.replace("/other-page?address=" + index.formatted_address);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having got some help from GetAddress.io - it turns out the elem is no longer an array but an object that you simply access using the properties e.g. elem.county

```
building_name: ""
building_number: "44"
country: "England"
county: "East Sussex"
district: "Brighton And Hove"
formatted_address: (3) ["40 Wordsworth Street", "Hove", "East Sussex"]
line_1: "40 Wordsworth Street"
line_2: ""
line_3: ""
line_4: ""
locality: ""
sub_building_name: ""
sub_building_number: ""
thoroughfare: "Wordsworth Street"
town_or_city: "Hove"
```